# Which are the written words that appears in "Mad Max: Fury Road" between the scene of the tree and the chain and the scene of Joe´s death?

Tags: mad-max, mad-max-fury-road

One particulary notable thing about this movie is that there is no so much written words. Reckon on this, the title contains the word road and the audience might expect road signs with pronouns. Regarding on this, the filmakers' challenge was truly that.

At the time being I can not remenber any written word. Perhaps this movie is about procedure memory. Maybe a sign that appear is the one that it helps the driver to control the revolutions of the engine, the gearbox, there should be more but not so many.

In the film *Prometheus* something similar happens.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Are you wanting to know if there was any writing period, or whether the decision to have not very much writing was a stylistic choice?

Comment: I reckon that it was a stylistic choice.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen a road sign that has pronouns. The closest would be signs like "stop" that use the [imperative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood#Usage), where the pronoun is only implied.

Comment: @Laurel FWIW in the first revisions it was "pronoums" and I was the one to change into pronouns as it looked like a typo, but in hindsight if you think that might be something else, I'm listening :)

Comment: @Laurel it is a really strange thing to watch a movie about roads without the names of the cities in the road signs. I think by watching the movie we are wating for that, the name of the citadel.

Answer (score 6):

The War Boys still know how to write, as evidenced by Max getting an ID tattoo giving away his blood types and some of his characteristics (eyes, scars...)

[image: Carved tattoo]

When Immortan Joe realizes his wives are gone, the following sentences can be seen written on the walls:

- "Our babies will not be warlords"
- "We are not things"
- "Who killed the world?"

Comment: Pretty sure Furiosa also has something written on the truck. It was either on the dash, or the steering wheel or something (can't recall properly).

Comment: Do you know how to locate that scene? Between which minutes?

Comment: @Feuergeist I took the screenshots off YouTube clips, but going from memory, tattoos should be at 7-8 minutes in, wives lost at maybe 15-20 minutes? Both scenes are quite early in the film. I'll try to grab a copy and get back to you

Comment: So great your work Jenayah. I will watch the film as soon as possible.